# How to create files to a specific folder in android application?

Tags: android

In my application, I want to create a text file in the cache folder and first what I do is create a folder in the cache directory.

```
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "MySecretFolder");
myDir.mkdir();
```

Then I want to create a text file in that created folder using the following code that doesn't seem to make it there. Instead, the code below creates the text file in the "files" folder that is in the same directory as the "cache" folder.

```
FileOutputStream fOut = null;
            try {
                fOut = openFileOutput("secret.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String str = "data";
            try {
                fOut.write(str.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

SO my question is, how do I properly designate the "MySecretFolder" to make the text file in?

I have tried the following:

**"/data/data/com.example.myandroid.cuecards/cache/MySecretFolder"**, but it crashes my entire app if I try that. How should I properly save the text file in the **cache/MySecretFolder**?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**use getCacheDir(). It returns the absolute path to the application-specific cache directory on the filesystem. Then you can create your directory**

```
File myDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "folder");
myDir.mkdir();
```

Please try this maybe helps you.

Ok, If you want to create the TextFile in Specific Folder then You can try to below code.

```
try {
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
        File root = new File(rootPath);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File f = new File(rootPath + "mttext.txt");
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }
        f.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I am assuming you haven't read my question. I wish to learn how to create a text file in a specified directory. I already know how to create a directory..

Comment: This will create MyFolder inside External storage.. but question is to add folder in Cache directory....

Comment: If you want to add folder in cache directory then change the rootpath as      rootpath = myDir.getAbsolutepath(); as i created above.

Answer (score 3):

Just change

```
fOut = openFileOutput("secret.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to

```
fOut = openFileOutput(myDir+"/secret.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

This will make **secret.txt** under **MySecretFolder**

Comment: I see, we can do this because mydir is alreadu the address and if it doesnt exist it'll just create the text file.

Comment: I don't think that's the right way, official doc says that you can't write path separator inside the openFileOutput function.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi : Agree to you... we should not use path seperator in `openFileOutput` parameter Thanks for correction

Answer (score 1):

getPrivateDir will create a folder in your private area (Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE- use what suits you from Context.MODE_...)

```
public File getPrivateDir(String name)
{
    return context.getDir(name, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
}
```

openPrivateFileInput will create a file if it doesn't exist in your private folder in files directory and return a FileInputStream :

```
/data/data/your.packagename/files
```

Your application private folder is in

```
/data/data/your.packagename 

public FileInputStream openPrivateFileInput(String name) throws  FileNotFoundException
{
    return context.openFileInput(name);
}
```

If you package name is uno.due.com your app private folder is:

```
/data/data/uno.due.com
```

All directories underneath are weather created by you or by android for you. When you create a file as above it will go under:

```
/data/data/uno.due.com/files
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy code to create folder, file and write/append into the file

```
try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newfoldername/";    // it will return root directory of internal storage
        File root = new File(path);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();       // create folder if not exist 
        }
        File file = new File(rootPath + "log.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();   // create file if not exist 
        }
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        buf.append("hi this will write in to file");
        buf.newLine();  // pointer will be nextline
        buf.close();

    } 
 catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

NOTE: It needs the Android External Storage Permission so  add below line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```