# Writing a file to internal storage

Tags: android, file, storage

I am trying to write a txt file to my android phone so that I can transfer it to my laptop and use the data. However whenever I write the file it is saving to Storage/emulated/0/Documents. I can't seem to access the emulated folder anywhere. Is there any way to just save to the documents folder that I see when I open it on my phone?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
myExternalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fName);

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
            fos.write(wifiInfo.getBytes());
            fos.close();
```

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Documents`. That directory is accessable for any file explorer app on your device. And also accessable from pc if you use the usb cable.

Comment: @greenapps

I can't see that when I access my phone via USB. I tried downloading a File Manager called FX File Manager which lets me view the emulated folder (not available with the default one). However when I try to access it I get an access denied message.

Comment: `(not available with the default one). ` ? I have no idea where you are talking about.

Comment: A normal file explorer should start in `/storage/emulated/0/`. Siarting in `/storage/emulated/` will not bring you far as the `0` subdir will not be there.

Comment: @greenapps after attempting to write to storage/emulated/0/Documents I plugged my phone into my laptop and opened it up. [This is what I saw](https://i.imgur.com/DuS1avg.png)

And this is [inside the documents folder](https://i.imgur.com/NtYubWy.png)

Answer (score 0):

[How to create files to a specific folder in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304616/how-to-create-files-to-a-specific-folder-in-android-application)

Basically you should be changing the FileOutputStream you are creating to the specific path you want to create the file in.

The link above has pretty detailed explanations.

Comment: This seems to be in order to write privately to internal storage. I'm looking to write non private files that I can access from the file manager.