# Itext7 Stopped at PdfWriter with FileNotFoundException Error

Tags: android-studio, itext7

I tried to make PDF file with Itext 7.2.2 and it just stop working at PdfWriter (im using Log to find where it stop) but the application doesnt crash. Here is my part of the code:

```
public void createPDF(ArrayList<ModelAttendance> arrayListAttendances, Integer attendeeCount){
    try{
        Log.i(TAG, "Create PDF with " +attendeeCount +" Attendee");

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Kegiatan/" + eventNama + ".pdf";

        File file = new File(path);
        file.mkdirs();

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, new PageSize(612, 936).rotate());
        document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        ...
    }
}
```

This the error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Kegiatan/Kegiatan 2.pdf (Is a directory)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:308)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:238)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:119)
W/System.err:     at com.itextpdf.commons.utils.FileUtil.getBufferedOutputStream(FileUtil.java:201)
W/System.err:     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.<init>(PdfWriter.java:138)
W/System.err:     at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter.<init>(PdfWriter.java:125)
W/System.err:     at id.go.hulusungaiselatankab.absensikegiatanpemerintahan.HelperClassPDF7.createPDF(HelperClassPDF7.java:42)
W/System.err:     at id.go.hulusungaiselatankab.absensikegiatanpemerintahan.ActivityAttendance.lambda$onCreate$0$id-go-hulusungaiselatankab-absensikegiatanpemerintahan-ActivityAttendance(ActivityAttendance.java:86)
W/System.err:     at id.go.hulusungaiselatankab.absensikegiatanpemerintahan.ActivityAttendance$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Im using PDF Reader Application and i dont find any file. However the code create another folder with "Kegiatan 2.pdf" as its name.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code from:

```
  File file = new File(path);
  file.mkdirs();
```

To:

```
  File root = new File(path);
  if (!root.exists()){
       root.mkdirs();
  }

  File file = new File(path  + eventNama + ".pdf");
  if(root.exists()){
       file.delete();
  }
  file.createNewFile();

  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

I got the answer from here: [How to create files to a specific folder in android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32304667/11729546)